# C#:Winform: How to do verification in mouse click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# winform application which displays some custom controls in TabPages, and user can move the controls around in the tabpage. However, each move needs to be verified in the business model. There are certain business rules need to be applied to verify the new location of the controls are valid or not.

How can I implement this in an efficient way ?

For example, a rectangle locates on (100,100) in the tabPage. In the model, it actually represents a vessel.
x represents the location on the berth, and Y represents the berthing datetime.

User could move this rectangle to a new berth or a new datetime, in the data model, it needs to verify it is a valid move or not. The verification needs to read some data from the model which will affect the verification.

Comment: to verify after every mouse-click is the wrong approach. because he could also navigate with the keyboard if you havnt completly disabled this. every time when the tab changes, then you could verify if he's permitted to change the tab

Comment: Can you give extra examples. This is very brief.

Comment: It depends on the business model complexity you didn't describe. If it's static you can "hardcode rules" to win speed (against 'coding style'). You also can create some sort of hashing if combinations are not complex when drag starts (e.g. store a hash of odd and even numbers to the different controls and verify if source and destination are both -e.g.- even), can also broadcast/fire an event describing the control and potential destinations set e.g. a "canAccept" property on themselves - etc, etc. Really depends on model & rules apply...

Comment: Can you attach events to your custom controls?

Comment: Sounds to me you should validate in the MouseUp event, the one that drops the rectangle in a new location.  The way this custom control works is less than clear.